# Run Excel Macro from Access macro in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am trying to run an excel macro from access 2016. This has a lot of examples out their however they are all old. The exact error code I receive is run-time error '1004':
cannot run the macro "TestScript()". The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be displayed. I am only running something easy for the test. I have ensured that macros is enabled in excel. the excel code is as follows

```
Public Sub TestScript()
   MsgBox "IT WORKED"
End Sub
```

Real simple for the test. Access is opening the excel spreadsheet however it stops there with an error code.

My Access code is very simple and is below. I have also noted where the code stops. While I am new at VBA I have done a lot of research in this. I am testing as simple code as I could figure out. Any help would be welcomed.

```
Option Compare Database

Function runExcelmacro()

    Dim XL As Object
    
    Set XL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    
    With XL

        'Turn Off warnings
        .Visible = False
        .displayalerts = False
        'WorkBook path such as "C:\Computer\WorkBook.xlsx"
    
        .Workbooks.Open "C:\DATABASE\BLQ-10\Import Database BLQ 10\NTIRAINSTALLTO.xlsm"
        'Run the Macro in excel getworkbook

        .Run TestScript 'Code stops here!

        'Close Workbook
        .ActiveWorkbook.Close (True)
        .Quite
    End With
    Set XL = Nothing

End Function


Public Sub runMacroSub()
    Call runExcelmacro("C:\DATABASE\BLQ-10\Import Database BLQ 10\NTIRAINSTALLTO.xlsm", "TestScript")
End Sub
```

Comment: Does `.run "testscript" ` generate the same error?

Comment: Also, `Dim xl as excel.application` and `set xl=.workbooks.open(….)` may be better?

Comment: you are right I changed it to TestScipt from that and it is running know the issue is nothing is happening! i do see a little message box open up

Comment: hmm let me change that and test

Comment: Nope i did that and it just gave me a bunch of new errors

Comment: Any idea what the errors are? :o)

Comment: I think the issue is that you are not referencing the workbook at all. You are only referencing the application which has a different set of properties and methods than a workbook does.

Comment: `XL` will exist as object type, holding the application.  I think you should use the excel reference and use `set xl=new excel.application` and then `set wb=xl.workbooks.open` etc.

Comment: Where did you put the macro in the excel workbook?

Comment: yes the macro is in the workbook and not personel

Comment: Where exactly? In an extra module?

Comment: I commented out the visible = false and did visible =true the workbook opens the issue is running the macro in excel

Comment: Sorry I do not understand what you mean. See my answer, maybe it helps.

Comment: It is located in the Modules folder. Do you have a recommendation of placement?

Comment: Then your macro works for me.  I just added quotation marks around `Testscript` as Nathan_Sav wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess OP did not put the code of `Testscript` in an extra module. Instead the code was put into the class module of the workbook or a worksheet. In the latter case you have to add the workbook or worksheet name in front of the name of the script.

Either it is `

```
.Run "ThisWorkbook.TestScript"
```

or in case it is in `Sheet1` ([codename](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-worksheet/#Using_the_Code_Name_of_a_Worksheet) of the sheet!)

```
.Run "Sheet1.TestScript"
```

Do not forget the quotation marks!

**PS** The OP's code above is working if you put `testscript` into a module and add quotation marks.

```
.Run "TestScript"
```

[Here](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-macro-create/#Step_5Create_a_Module) is a description how to create a module and add code

Comment: Figures LOL More examples of why detail is necessary

Comment: nice this made the function work know it won't close .ActiveWorkbook.Close (True)

Comment: Code above is working for me fine in case `Testscript` is located in the workbook or worksheet module. It's difficult to tell where you have trouble if you more or less only say that it does not work.

Comment: how do i say this is the answer?

Comment: Storax is my hero!

Answer (score 0):

Here try this:

```
Public Sub TestScript()
   MsgBox "IT WORKED"
End Sub

Option Compare Database

Function runExcelmacro()
    Dim XL As Object, wb as object
    Set XL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    With XL
        .Visible = False
        .displayalerts = False
        set wb = .Workbooks.Open "C:\DATABASE\BLQ-10\Import Database BLQ 10\NTIRAINSTALLTO.xlsm"
        wb.Run TestScript 'Code stops here!
        .ActiveWorkbook.Close (True)
        .Quite
    End With
    Set XL = Nothing

End Function

Public Sub runMacroSub()
    Call runExcelmacro("C:\DATABASE\BLQ-10\Import Database BLQ 10\NTIRAINSTALLTO.xlsm", "TestScript")
End Sub
```

Here i declared wb as an object and then set wb = to the workbook.

This is of course assumin your test script is in the actual workbook being opened. Would be real funny if that wasnt a thing lol

Comment: Hey, i changed the code and get this run-time error 438 Object dosn't support this property or method as wb.run TestScript