# MS Access: Export query to Excel and run VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have a query `queryWeeklyReport` and a script (namely `export`) whose job is to export the query into an Excel file (`export.xlsx`).

I also have another macro-enabled excel file (`formatting.xlsm`) which contains the macro for formatting the `export.xlsx` file.

What I have been doing is to

1. Run the `export` script
2. Open the `formatting.xlsm` and `export.xlsx` spreadsheets
3. Go to Developers tab and run the macro contained in the `formatting.xlsm` file.

How could I include the last two steps in the `export` script so that whenever I run it, the Excel macro will run on the `export.xlsx` file?

Comment: There probably is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run Excel Macro from Access macro in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59879272/run-excel-macro-from-access-macro-in-vba)